# second div inside another not appearing?

Tags: html, css

I have a page set up like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="right">
    ...
  </div>

  <div id="left">
    <div id="top">...</div>
    <div id="bottom">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}

#wrapper #right {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#wrapper #left {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 200px
  top: 150px;
  margin-left: -230px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#wrapper #left #top {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#wrapper #left #bottom {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

For some reason the bottom div inside the left div isn't showing up.  Any explanation as to why it's not showing up?  And is there a solution?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we have some CSS?

Comment: Can you show any CSS styling? A jsFiddle showcasing the issue would be really great.

Comment: Does it show up if you put some text in it

Comment: Whoops, added the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `float:left;`, the `<div>` will not take up space, so the bottom `<div>` is behind the top div. To fix this problem, get take out `float:left;` from the top `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing. Check http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pzqoi

```
#wrapper {background:#f4f4f4; height:960px;}
#right{background:#f4f4f4; border:1px solid #ccc; float:right;}

#left {background:#f4f4f4; border:1px solid #ccc; float:left; padding:10px;}
#top {background:#f4f4f4; border:1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom:5px;}
#bottom {background:#f4f4f4; border:1px solid #ccc; clear:both;}
```